# Caret install package, had non-zero exit in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit

Tags: r, ubuntu

When trying to install the caret package on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit I received the following warnings

```
The downloaded source packages are in

‘/tmp/RtmpnrWGAe/downloaded_packages’ 



 Warning messages:  
1: In install.packages("caret") :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status   
2: In install.packages("caret") :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status  
3: In install.packages("caret") :
  installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status  
4: In install.packages("caret") :
  installation of package ‘BradleyTerry2’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("caret") :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status  
6: In install.packages("caret") :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install all of the dependencies prior to installing the 'caret' package.

```
install.packages(c('lme4', 'pbkrtest', 'BradleyTerry2', 'car', 'caret'))
```

The above code should fix the issue.

Or you could use:

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)
```

You can then attempt to install the 'nloptr' package using the above command.